# What are some examples of sporadic groups in physics?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

The existence of sporadic groups is strange in the sense that it seems unnatural. As group theory is unavoidable in physics, have we found that there are things in nature that are better described by sporadic groups? Which ones?

According to this paper [Introduction to sporadic groups for physicists](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.5974) (Boya, 2013), there are apparently some uses in string theory. Are there any other uses of sporadic groups in lower energy physics?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind are, well, using conformal field theories. I suspect there's probably some way to get sporadic groups using lattice QFT, but in 24 dimensions (or something strange like that).